# How to make a comma separated string in list inside another list C#?

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects (`Bookings`). Inside that I have a another list of objects (`Products`).

I need to get comma-separated product id's from this method

I have used for each and it's working fine

```
private static string GetProductIDs(List<BookingModel>? Bookings)
{

    List<long> ProductIDS = new List<long>();

    foreach (var booking in Bookings)
    {
        var products = booking?.Products ;
        if (products != null)
        {
            foreach (var product in products)
            {
                if (product.ProductID != null)
                {
                    ProductIDS.Add((long)product.ProductID);
                }

            }
        }   

    }
    return string.Join(",", ProductIDS.ToArray());

}
```

when I try the below code it's returning an error. could you please help me with the Best idea to do this?

```
var test = Bookings.SelectMany(c => c.Products.Where(p => p.ProductID != null)
    .Select(t => t.ProductID))
    .ToList();
               
return string.Join(",", test.ToArray());
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: What is the error, and where is it occuring?

Comment: Why are you casting to list followed by casting to array? Is there some further usage? If there is only 1 usage of `test` consider just using `.ToArray()`

Comment: If you can compare `product.ProductID` with `null`, it's highly likely that you can't directly cast it to `long`, you should use `long.Parse`.

Comment: Is `ProductID` an `long`? Maybe `long?` (nullable)? Because a basic `long` property can **never** be null.

Comment: Try : .Where(p => (p != null) && (p.ProductID != null))

Comment: You have nonsensical null handling. E.g., you declare a `List<BookingModel>? Bookings` parameter. According to this declaration the list can be null, but the list elements cannot; however, you never check whether the list is null but do check if the elements are null. If elements can be null, then declare the list as `List<BookingModel?>` (note: the ? is inside the <>). My advice: Don't allow null elements in lists and ensure lists to be assigned (e.g., through field or property initializers). This will simplify things a lot.

Comment: Also, the `.ToArray()` call at the end is not needed at all and just wastes RAM and CPU.

Comment: [Debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger) your code and you will see what is `null`. I guess it's `Bookings` in `Bookings.SelectMany(...)`. And please, don't insert errors a image. Add them as text (see the "Copy Details" link in your image?). And also we still don't know on which code line. Visual Studio tells you this.

Answer (score 2):

I would move the final `string.Join()` out of the method. Change the method design to return an `IEnumerable<long>`, and then use that result to produce the final comma-separated string.

Additionally, we can't see this for certain, but I suspect at least part of the error is you have a nullable `long?`, instead of a simple `long` for `ProductID`. Otherwise there would be no point in checking whether `ProductID` was `null`, as primitive values like `long` can **never** be null.

So the new method looks like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<long> GetProductIDs(IEnumerable<BookingModel>? Bookings)
{
    if (Bookings == null) return Enumerable.Empty<long>();

    return Bookings.Where(b => b.products is object).
               SelectMany(b => b.products.
                                 Where(p => p.ProductID.HasValue).
                                 Select(p => p.ProductID.Value)
                         );
}
```

And we can call it like this:

```
var result = string.Join(",", GetProductIDs(MyBookingList));
```

You might further want to take care to enforce a string format for the long=>string conversion that will not use additional comma separators between the segments of the numbers, which would throw off your CSV data. You get good behavior by default, but people can change it. You want to be sure it will continue to work regardless of what happens with the localization settings on the machine:

```
var result = string.Join(",", GetProductIDs(MyBookingList).Select(n => n.ToString("###"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var test = Bookings.SelectMany(c => c.Products.Where(p => p.ProductID != null))
.Select(x => x.ProductID)
.ToArray();
```

Comment: The `ToArray()` is not needed and wasteful.

Comment: same error I'm getting